# Compute degree of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and find a basis.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

This is a review problem for a Galois theory course.

Compute $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_8): \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)]$ and find a basis. (Where $\zeta_8$ is the primitive $8$th root of unity).

I compute the degree as follows:
Let $L= \mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$ and $K= \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Then $$[L:\mathbb Q] = [L:K][K:\mathbb Q].$$

It can be shown that $[L:\mathbb Q]=4$, since $\zeta_8$ is a root of the $8$th cyclotomic polynomial $x^4 +1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$, so it is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, of degree $4$. Also, clearly $[K: \mathbb Q]=2$ because the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2$ is $x^2-2$.

Plugging these into our equation we get that $[L:K]=2$.

Now to find a basis, I'm a bit lost. I would like to find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_8$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, though I'm not sure how.

I know that a basis of $L/\mathbb Q$ is $\{1, \zeta_8, \zeta_8^2, \zeta_8^3\}$, and a basis of $K/ \mathbb Q$ is $\{1, \sqrt 2\}$, but I'm not sure about $L/K$.

My first instinct is to say it will be something like $\{1, \zeta_8 \sqrt{2} \}$, but I'm unsure about it.

Comment: Good grief. Write down the number $\zeta_8$ explicitly!

Comment: @TedShifrin I can see that $\zeta_8 = e^{\pi i / 4}$, but I must be missing something obvious that you are hinting at.

Comment: Yes, write down that complex number explicitly!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you :)

Comment: You’re welcome. Sometimes we forget to try the obvious!

Comment: @TedShifrin Would a basis then be $\{ 1, \sqrt 2 i \}$?

Comment: Or just $1,i$? …